# How can I pass an argument to a Scala Macro Annotation impl?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

I have success when the annotation's argument is a literal, like:

```
@Annotation(2)
class AnnotatedClass
```

since I can get the value in the macro's `impl` with:

```
c.prefix.tree match {
  case Apply(_, List(Literal(Constant(x)))) => x.toInt
}
```

But I'm stumped when the annotation's argument is not a literal, like:

```
object Obj {val n = 2}

@Annotation(Obj.n)
class AnnotatedClass
```

Similar to the false-start in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791686/type-parameters-on-scala-macro-annotations), I can match `c.prefix.tree` again and pull out the names `Obj` and `n`, but how do I get the value of `Obj.n`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment it's virtually impossible. Evaluation of trees is essentially not supported by our macro system (we have `c.eval`, but its current implementation is slow and only works reliably with literal arguments).