# Macro annotations and type parameter

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm not sure whether its duplicate of [Type Parameters on Scala Macro Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791686/type-parameters-on-scala-macro-annotations) or not.

I'm trying to get type parameter on macro annotation:

```
class builder extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro builderMacro.impl
}
//....
val q"new $_[$tpt]().macroTransform(..$_)" = c.macroApplication
val tpe = c.typecheck(tpt).tpe
// also tried
// val tpe = c.typecheck(q"None.asInstanceOf[$tpt]").tpe
```

Code that uses macro:

```
object Test2 {
  trait TestBuilders

  @builder[TestBuilders]
  case class TestClass(x: Int, opt1: Option[String], opt2: Option[String])  {
    val opts = (opt1, opt2)
  }
}
```

and exception i get:

```
[error] scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: not found: type TestBuilders
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Typers.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Typers.scala:28)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.withMode(Contexts.scala:374)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$3.apply(Typers.scala:24)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$3.apply(Typers.scala:24)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$withContext$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$withContext$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.withMode(Contexts.scala:374)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$1.apply(Typers.scala:23)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$1.apply(Typers.scala:23)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$class.withContext$1(Typers.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2.apply(Typers.scala:28)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2.apply(Typers.scala:28)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.wrappingIntoTerm(Trees.scala:1691)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.wrappingIntoTerm(SymbolTable.scala:16)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$class.withWrapping$1(Typers.scala:26)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$class.typecheck(Typers.scala:28)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.typecheck(Context.scala:6)
[error]         at builderMacro$.impl(Macros.scala:55)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: ok.. i was able to use just `tpt` Tree without actual Type. but i still don't understand why i can't get type here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in current macro paradise: https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/14. Note that if `TestBuilders` is declared in a different scope, everything should work out.